# How to disable fade in scrolling effect on mobile with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using javascript to create a fade-in and fade-out effect based on scroll position. The scrolling is very jittery on mobile so I am looking to disable it completely. How can I disable this on devices under 767pixels?

I have tried implementing window.matchMedia(): But I cannot figure out how to make it work. Thank you for reading.

```
const scrollElements = document.querySelectorAll(".fade-up, .fade-in, .reveal");

const elementInView = (el, dividend = 1) => {
  const elementTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;

  return (
    elementTop <=
    (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) / dividend
  );
};

const elementOutofView = (el, dividend = 1) => {
  const elementTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;

  return (
    elementTop > (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) / dividend
  );
};

const displayScrollElement = (element) => {
  element.classList.add("is-visible");
};

const hideScrollElement = (element) => {
  element.classList.remove("is-visible");
};

const handleScrollAnimation = () => {
  scrollElements.forEach((el) => {
    if (elementInView(el, 1.05)) {
      displayScrollElement(el);
    } else if (elementOutofView(el, 1.05)) {
      hideScrollElement(el)
    }
  })
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => { 
  handleScrollAnimation();
});
```

Comment: Just use css media queries to overide stuff when in mobile, use `!important` if you have too. Worth checking out [Scroll Reveal](https://scrollrevealjs.org/) btw, works lovely on mobile!

Comment: Great suggestion, do not know why I didn't think of that, lol. Thank you !

Comment: Scroll reveal looks amazing. Do you know of any similar free options that work well on mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scroll Reveal works pretty good for free for me.

See simple example below making bootstrap `.card` elements fade in.

I've changed the fade in animation [`duration`](https://scrollrevealjs.org/api/duration.html) to `2000ms` in this example but check out [ScrollReveal docs](https://scrollrevealjs.org/api/duration.html) for loads of other cool options.

https://scrollrevealjs.org/api/duration.html

Here is simplest example below of quick usage...

*Doesn't work in stack overflow code preview iframe but it works in jsfiddle, see fiddle link below*

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/jh18vwpy/14/

```js
// scroll reveal js... job done :-)
ScrollReveal().reveal('.card', {
  duration: 2000 
});
```

```css
.card {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal@4.0.9/dist/scrollreveal.js"></script>

<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="https://scrollrevealjs.org/">ScrollReveal in Bootstrap 4</a>
  </nav>
</header>

<main class="pt-3 pb-3">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x200&amp;text=thumbnail" class="card-img-top" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x200&amp;text=thumbnail" class="card-img-top" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x200&amp;text=thumbnail" class="card-img-top" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x200&amp;text=thumbnail" class="card-img-top" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x200&amp;text=thumbnail" class="card-img-top" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x200&amp;text=thumbnail" class="card-img-top" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x200&amp;text=thumbnail" class="card-img-top" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x200&amp;text=thumbnail" class="card-img-top" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x200&amp;text=thumbnail" class="card-img-top" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x200&amp;text=thumbnail" class="card-img-top" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x200&amp;text=thumbnail" class="card-img-top" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x200&amp;text=thumbnail" class="card-img-top" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</main>
```

---

Update on how you can add scrollreveal to wordpress theme.

Add this to your `functions.php`...

```php
// enqueue scrollreveal script
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scrollreveal');

// enqueue scrollreveal script function
function enqueue_scrollreveal() {

    // register scrollreveal lib
    wp_register_script('scrollreveal-lib', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/scrollReveal.js/4.0.9/scrollreveal.min.js', [], '4.0.9', false);

    // enqueue scrollreveal lib
    wp_enqueue_script('scrollreveal-lib');

    // add inline script to execute scrollreveal
    wp_add_inline_script('scrollreveal-js',
        'ScrollReveal().reveal('.wp-block-post', { 
            duration: 2000 
        });'
    );  

}
```

Find the element `class` in your source that you wish for scrollreveal to fade in. In the my example i've used `.wp-block-post`, simply replace this with a class used in your theme.

Comment: This will take me some time to learn how to implement into Wordpress with an animation I like. Im willing to dive into this though because it looks fun to learn =) ...Plus the documentation looks straight forward.
Thank you for the demo!!

Comment: @Josh I've added an update to my answer on how your can add scrollreveal to your wordpress theme 